# Is there a concise functional way to assert types of elements in a collection?

Tags: typescript

Let's say we want to collect the names of all checkboxes on a page.

The most naive solution would be

```
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')]
    .map(el => el.name);
```

It does not pass type checking because `document.querySelectorAll` returns a collection of `Element`, that does not have a `name` property.

One way to fix it could be to explicitly specify the type parameter `document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>`.

It would make a compiler happy, not me: now this code is not type safe and may fail in runtime.

A type safe solution might look

```
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .filter(el => el.matches('[type=checkbox]'))
    .map(el => el.name);
```

but it would make code more verbose, less clear and in general this solution does not scale (here I mean that you cannot generically apply it, since not every selector can be split as easily).

And finally, the one with both static and runtime checks

```
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')]
    .reduce((acc, el) => el instanceof HTMLInputElement ? [...acc, el] : acc, [] as HTMLInputElement[])
    .map(el => el.name);
```

it's the safest yet the ugliest.

Finally, my question: is there no way to make it as safe as the latest option but a bit more readable?

Comment: What does the additional type safety accorded by the ugly version actually buy you?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's not "additional" it's just "type safety". Other options in the question are not type safe.

Comment: Why are you unhappy with `document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>`. You have info the compiler does not... I would use this version

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir now if a selector changes slightly ever without changing a generic parameter - you may get problems in runtime (yet it would still be type checked)

Comment: Your 'type safe' version will cause problems too if there is a miss match between query and type. If the selector returns more but you filter out some values it might cause unexpected behavior.. The shortest version is probably to use `filter` with a type guard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a type guard with `filter` to filter out the unwanted nodes and change the type of the array :

```
const names = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')]
    .filter((el): el is HTMLInputElement => el instanceof HTMLInputElement)
    .map(el => el.name);
```