# How fix this typescript error: Property "nodename" doesn't exist

Tags: typescript

Line of code is

```
 readXML(): void {
    // testing the function
    let xmlstr = `<book><title>Some title</title>
                  <description>some description </description>
                  <author>
                      <id>1</id>
                      <name>some author name</name>
                  </author>
                  <review>nice book</review>
                  <review>this book sucks</review>
                  <review>amazing work</review></book>
                  `;

    // converting to DOM Tree
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const srcDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlstr, "application/xml");
    // Converting DOM Tree To JSON. 
    console.log(this.xml2json(srcDOM));
  }


  xml2json(srcDOM): any {
    const children = Array.from(srcDOM.children);

    // base case for recursion. 
    if (!children.length) {
      return srcDOM.innerHTML
    }

    // initializing object to be returned. 
    let jsonResult = {};

    for (let child of children) {
      // checking is child has siblings of same name. 
      let childIsArray = children.filter(eachChild => eachChild.nodeName === child.nodeName).length > 1;

      // if child is array, save the values as array, else as strings. 
      if (childIsArray) {
        if (jsonResult[child.nodeName] === undefined) {
          jsonResult[child.nodeName] = [this.xml2json(child)];
        } else {
          jsonResult[child.nodeName].push(this.xml2json(child));
        }
      } else {
        jsonResult[child.nodeName] = this.xml2json(child);
      }
    }

    return jsonResult;
  };
```

This item is problematic `eachchild.nodeName` and throwing the following error
`Property 'nodeName' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Code runs as expected... How do I tell Typescript what this object is and that it does have that property??

Thanks!!

Context: I  am traversing an XML string.

Comment: You could check that `eachChild` is of particular type using `instanceof`

Comment: Also, probably relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54877121/251311

Comment: TypeScript is case sensitive, and you’ve spelled it as `nodename` and `nodeName`, only the latter of which is correct...

Comment: Please edit the question to include enough code to reproduce the problem. With just the code you've given, we have no idea what the type of `children` is. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: where are you getting this child object? are you creating it? getting it from an api? please show more code

Comment: sorry, I thought it was noise to show everything. I have updated it to show the calling function that passes a DOM tree.